# Interior and closure of open interval $\left(0, \infty \right)$ in $\mathbb R$

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

From my understanding, the interior of $\left(0, \infty \right)$ is $\left(0, \infty \right)$ because the interior of an open interval is the same open interval. Regarding the closure, I'm confused because

- The closure of a set is the same set in addition to its limit points, which would make the closure $\left[0, \infty \right)$.
- The closure is the complement of the interior, which would make the closure $\{0\}$.

Those two things I stated above contradict each other so I know that incorrectly determined either the interior or the closure of this set. Where am I going wrong?

Comment: The closure of $(0,\infty)$ in $\mathbb{R}$ **is** $[0,\infty)$. The closure is **not** the complement of the interior.

Comment: @copper.hat oh...I misread "The interior of S is the complement of the closure of the complement of S." from [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interior_(topology))

Comment: Where did you hear that the closure is the complement of the interior?

Answer (score 1):

Look again at the definitions: The closure of a set $A$ is the intersection of all closed sets containing $A$ ("smallest closed set containing $A$") and the interior of $A$ is the union of all open sets contained in $A$ ("largest open set contained in $A$"). Is the second statement you have said true?

Comment: As I said to copper hat I misread the definition [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interior_(topology))

Answer (score 0):

Let $x\in (0,\infty)$; for $\epsilon:=\frac x2>0$ we ensure that $N_x(\epsilon)=(x-\epsilon,x+\epsilon)=(\frac x2,\frac {3x}{2})\subseteq (0,\infty)$, so $(0,\infty)^\circ=(0,\infty)$, because we just showed that $(0,\infty)$ is an open set.

About the closure; we want to show that $[0,\infty)=\overline A$. Let $x\in [0,\infty)$ and $\epsilon >0$; then $N^*_x(\epsilon)\cap(0,\infty)\neq \varnothing$, where $N^*_x(\epsilon)=(x-\epsilon,x+\epsilon)\setminus\{x\}$,  thus $x\in \overline A$, namely $[0,\infty)\subseteq\overline A$. For the reverse inclusion; let $x\in \overline A$ and $x\notin [0,\infty)$; then, for $\epsilon:=\frac {|x|}{2}>0$, $N_x^*(\epsilon)\cap[0,\infty)=\varnothing$, so $x\notin \overline A$, which recommends a contradiction. Thus $x\in [0,\infty)$, so $\overline A\subseteq [0,\infty)$. In conclusion $[0,\infty)=\overline A$. q.e.d.